# how to get data through a stored procedure in wcf?

Tags: wcf, stored-procedures

I am working on a wcf application where i want to access some columns from a table (prefebly via stored procedure) through wcf and pass it to client. I have searched a lot on the google but unable to find a good example of it. Can some one help me please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which bit are you having difficulty with? Writing a WCF method, or calling a stored procedure?

Comment: calling a stored procedure which returns multiple rows in a wcf service is causing me problem

Comment: i tried following

public List<TBL_CONTENTTEMPLATE> GetTemplates()
        {
            RSPALinqDataContext rspaLinq = new RSPALinqDataContext();

            return rspaLinq.TBL_CONTENTTEMPLATEs.ToList();
        }
here TBL_CONTENTTEMPLATE is a table and i am getting all the records of it. I want to do similar thing and get all the data from the stored procedure or some of the columns from the above table(with or without linq).
thanks

Comment: sorry for above ugly formatting, i dont know why all the enter spaces of the code were removed by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the DB APIs will allow you access to SQL. Recently, I've used mostly the [Entity Frameworks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx) with my WCF services. All was fine and dandy, once you get the connection string(s) worked out to each of your databases.

Comment: thanks for replying, i have no problem in accessing sql server but when i try to fetch multible rows from a table using stored procedure i am not able to do it.

Comment: What I did was use the Entities design surface and Server Explorer to drag over the stored procs I was interested in and then they were in the datacontext.StoredProc(...).

Answer (score 0):

erm write a datacontract serializable class and have a method on it to populate itself using a connection object?

Comment: i have tried that and it works when i execute a procedure for inserting, updating or deleting in database but when i try to get records in multiple columns i am not getting it. I need a datatable with records and return it to client. I have done it so many times in web forms but not in wcf services. it will be great if u can provide me some sample code as i m new in wcf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your types are serializable. Based on your comment to PeanutPower's answer it looks like you'll need to make sure TBL_CONTENTTEMPLATE is serializable. Also verify you have your service contract defined on the client side to accept a collection type of System.Collections.Generic.List, the default is System.Array and I've run into problems in the past when the client contract was misconfigured in this way.